# My URL Regex is allowing spaces but shouldn't

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created a regex that seems to be quite stable in validating normal Http URLs, however, it seems to be allowing spaces to be entered anywhere but the protocol.

So, `http://dango me/mypage` is being allowed.

```
'is-url': function() {
    return /^(https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_+%-]+(.[a-zA-Z0-9+\_%-]+)*(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[a-zA-Z0-9+()?#~=&\._%-]*)*)?$/.test(this);
}
```

Comment: Because it's being encoded as "%20"?

Comment: The dot you need to escape it, also you made everything optional. Not sure if that is desired

Comment: @HamZa Yes, that was desired, I have a separate validation function for fields that are required. Allows me to split validation responses up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the dot:

```
return /^(https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_+%-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9+\_%-]+)*(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[a-zA-Z0-9+()?#~=&\._%-]*)*)?$/.test(this);
//                             here __^
```

without escaping it matches any character but newline so, of course, a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
> return /^(https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_+%-]+(.[a-z
```

I guess it is because you use . (dor meaning anythisn including space
it probably have to escape it and should be

```
 return /^(https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_+%-]+(\.[a-z
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the dot. `.` means 'match any character except newline' in regular expressions. If you want a literal dot, escape it like so `\.`.

```
'is-url': function() {
    return /^(https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_+%-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9+\_%-]+)*(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[a-zA-Z0-9+()?#~=&\._%-]*)*)?$/.test(this);
}
```